# CalenderView Resize issue with Orientation in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am using CalenderView in my Windows 10 UWP App and it works fine in Mobile View but I want to use same in Desktop and set a particular *Width* and *Height* for it so it displays perfectly but I am facing issue as shown in the following image

[image: Calener View]

My CalenderView XAML Code

```
<CalendarView x:Name="MyCalenderView"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Visibility="Collapsed"
              SelectedBorderBrush="#148BDF"
              CalendarItemBackground="#FFDDEBF7"
              DayItemFontSize="11"
              MonthYearItemFontSize="16"
              NumberOfWeeksInView="5"
              SelectedDatesChanged="MyCalenderView_SelectedDatesChanged">                  

         <CalendarView.CalendarViewDayItemStyle>
               <Style TargetType="CalendarViewDayItem">
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="35"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="35"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,4"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                           <Setter.Value>
                               <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarViewDayItem"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                     </Setter>
                  </Style>
             </CalendarView.CalendarViewDayItemStyle>
       </CalendarView>
```

Even I tried to add fixed Value for Height and Width but no luck. Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to handle this issue as per my requirement. I have added MaxWidth parameter for CalenderView as follows

```
<CalendarView x:Name="MyCalenderView"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Visibility="Collapsed"
          SelectedBorderBrush="#148BDF"
          CalendarItemBackground="#FFDDEBF7"
          DayItemFontSize="11"
          MonthYearItemFontSize="16"
          NumberOfWeeksInView="5"
          MaxWidth=320
          SelectedDatesChanged="MyCalenderView_SelectedDatesChanged">                  

     <CalendarView.CalendarViewDayItemStyle>
           <Style TargetType="CalendarViewDayItem">
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="35"/>
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="35"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,4"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                       <Setter.Value>
                           <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarViewDayItem"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                 </Setter>
              </Style>
         </CalendarView.CalendarViewDayItemStyle>
   </CalendarView>
```